# problems with select customization

Tags: html, css

I've been trying for a long time to find ways to make the dropdown color as transparent as the parent element in my video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwnyj7FSk8E). but my search didn't lead to anything.

I tried to apply these styles to an option or select element:

```
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;

 background: rgba($color: white, $alpha: .3);
```

but it didn't help and it's like there's a white background underneath that I can't affect

my html code and CSS generated by a webpack:

```css
body { background-color: black; }
.convert_block_item {
  display: flex;
}

.convert-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: calc((1vw + 1vh) * 7);
  height: calc((1vw + 1vh) * 1.5);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
}

.convert-wrap input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.convert-wrap input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.convert-wrap input {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.convert-wrap input:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.convert-wrap select {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.convert-wrap select:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.convert-wrap select option {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.conv-padding {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: calc((1vw + 1vh) * 0.5);
}

.convert1 {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: calc((1vw + 1vh) * 6.5);
}

.convert1 .convert-wrap {
  width: calc((1vw + 1vh) * 8);
}

.convert2 {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: calc((1vw + 1vh) * 7.5);
}

.cur {
  border-radius: 215px;
}
```

```html
<div class="convert_block_item convert2">
  <div class="convert-wrap">
    <select id="cur2" class="cur">
      <option>ETH</option>
      <option>BTN</option>
    </select>
    <div class="convert_result conv-padding">= 00,00</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I made you a [mcve]

Comment: your `div.convert-wrap` has a `background-color` (greyish) that when you the `background-color` of the `select` (dropdown) to `transparent `, the gryish background will be visible and you'll think that the dropdown is not transparent but you were fooled by `.convert-wrap` background.

Comment: @mplungjan thx, but do you know how I can reduce the transparency of the drop-down list?

Comment: @ths
even if I completely remove the background color of the parent, the dropdown will remain white

Comment: @ШПИПСИКCHANNEL Please use `transparent` keyword: `background-color: transparent`.

Comment: @ths it didn't help